# Rest mysql password command , cmd not showing any output

Tags: mysql

MySQL Server 5.7

mysql-init.txt file:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
```

Tried using this command to change my root password

```
mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

but after inputting the command nothing happens. It feels like it is loading but I tried waiting for 1 hour and still no response.

[cmd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klCvX.png)

Comment: after restarting the unit, the password is still the root password, not the new one.

Comment: is there another way of changing the password other than that?

Comment: did you follow https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html exactly?

Comment: yes but when I try the mysql installation wizard step , after just typing mysqld nothing happens to my cmd

Comment: try connecting mysql via an application. I wouldn't expect mysqld to output anything. There's no point waiting beyond a few seconds, it should be pretty instantaneous. Maybe its the `root@'%'` user that you need to reset? They are distinct.